# How to display name in the url instead id in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have created an application in cakephp environment,
I am displaying the user profile using user_id in user profile page

I am sending the value to controller using anchor tag like below:
(I can't send the name because it is not unique).

```
<a href="/users/<?php echo $result['user']['id'];?>">View Profile</a>
```

Function in User Controller :

```
function viewprofile($userid){
 // my logic
}
```

the profile url is like  this:
http://www.xyz.com/users/12

I want to display the name of user instead user_id

How can we display name(with slug) in url in cakephp

Please help me

Comment: Your question is confusing - I answered best I could, but it's hard to tell what you're asking since you contradict yourself at least twice.

Comment: Hi Dave:

Actully In my user table have user_id, username , address...etc
I fetch the record of users using user_id so that I pass the user_id to controller. In the cakephp passed value shows in the url, which I have mentioned above.
Now I just want to show name of the user not id

Comment: k - so show the name.  I still don't know what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $this->Html->link('View Profile', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action'=> 'view',
    $result['user']['slug']
));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do 3 things.

1. Create unique User Slugs (you might have that already ;-) )
2. Create your links with the code Dave mentioned before

   echo $this->Html->link('View Profile', array('controller' => 'users','action'=> 'view',$result['user']['slug']));
3. tell your routing what to do (/app/condig/routes.php) with it

   Router::connect('/user/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));

Now you will get pretty urls and the slug will be a parameter that can be used to find the user in your User table

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
echo $this->Html->link('View Profile',array('plugin' => false,
                                            'controller' => 'users',
                                            'action' => 'view',
                                            "slug"=>$data['slug']));
```

And in your Routes file

```
Router::connectNamed(array('slug'));
    Router::connect('/user/:slug', array(
        'plugin' => false,
        'controller' => 'users', 
        'action' => 'view',
        ),array(
            "pass"=>array("slug")
        )
    );
```