# how to append the username in url instead of user_id in cakephp 3

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want my url like this format http://localhost/blog/users/username  instead of this http://localhost/blog/users/view/6

I have this code in Users view index.ctp

[image]

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<?= $this->Html->link(__('View Profile'), ['action' => 'view', $user['user']['slug']]) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

routes.php

```
<?php
 $routes->connect('/user/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));
?>


//public function view($id = null)
public function view($username)
{

    $users = $this->Users->get($username, [
        'contain' => ['Subjects'] // i have relation
    ]);
    $this->set('users', $users);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909241/how-to-display-name-in-the-url-instead-id-in-cakephp) but it not solved my problem

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
  //$logged_user_id=$this->request->Session()->read('Auth.user.id');


  $logged_user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');
  if($logged_user_id==$id){
      $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
      if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());


        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('User profile successfuly  updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('You are not allowed to do this.'));
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

}

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs  sorry I already included the routes.php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In index.ctp

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<?= $this->Html->link(__('View Profile'), ['action' => 'view', $user->username]) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please change `$user->username` as per your structure.

You don't have to do anything in your **routs.php**

the username will receive as an argument of the function view

```
function view($username){
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: what should I add to my code in view method to achieve? currently it shows this errors "Record not found in table "users" with primary key [NULL]".....after I tried <?= $this->Html->link(__('View Profile'), ['action' => 'view', $user->username]) ?> I added the view method above

Answer (score 1):

The `get` function uses the model's primary key field. It might be possible to change your primary key to `username`, but I suspect that will cause you other problems. Instead, try this:

```
$users = $this->Users->find('first')
    ->where(['username' => $username])
    ->contain(['Subjects']);
```

Also, is there a reason that your variable here is plural (`$users`)? You should only be getting a single user from this, right?

Comment: It says "Unknown finder method "first"   Yes it only getting 1 user when I click the view profile I added the screenshot in the questions above.

Comment: Do like this `$user = $this->Users->find()->where(['username' => $username])->contain(['Subjects'])->first();`

Comment: @AmanRawat  wow, thank you so much,   so it will not break the cakephp or cause problems, like Greg said, i will just create another method for this and retain the previous method "public function view with the parameter of $id"

Comment: @Greg, thank you so much for your help also,,,  AmanRawat, how to change ur code if their is no relation of SUBJECTS

Comment: Just remove the association `$user = $this->Users->find()->where(['username' => $username])->first();`

Comment: @AmanRawat, thanks for always helping me. see you in my next problem :) bro.

Comment: What do  you mean by "can't edit"? What happens when you try? Is there something different about editing your own compared to editing someone else's? According to the code you've shared to date, there should be no difference at all.

Comment: @GregSchmidt  I dont know what happen to my stackoverflow account , I cant ask questions anymore and SAYS'  "You have reached your question limit"     this is the scenario since I have a url like this one already http://localhost/blog/users/profile/username   I added a profile method, so if i try to edit my account which received get id as parameter, I also added above the edit method

Comment: I created dummy account to ask questions which found this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494342/cannot-edit-my-profile-after-changing-the-url-link-from-user-id-to-username-usin

Comment: According to your profile, you've asked over 20 questions here, but only answered one, and made almost no votes on anything. StackOverflow works best when people contribute to help others in the community, not just take help from others. Try to find some questions that you can help people out with. This will improve your reputation and allow you to post more questions.

Comment: oh no,   I accepted someone answer as useful and correct? that not counted as votes? and I should always votes other questions and answer to improved my profile?

Comment: The big thing is actually answering questions in a helpful way, like people do for you.