# Cannot edit my profile after changing the url link from user id to username using cakephp 3.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this method to display a user profile like this one in url http://localhost/sample/users/profile/john  instead of http://localhost/sample/users/view/1

```
public function profile($username)
{
    $user = $this->Users->find()->where(['username' => $username])->first(); 
    $accountUsername  =  $user->username;
    $this->set('profileUserName', $accountUsername);
    $this->set('users', $user);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

When I try to edit my profile It will always go to "You are not allowed to do this."

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
  $logged_user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');
  if($logged_user_id==$id){
      $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
      if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());


        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('User profile successfuly  updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('You are not allowed to do this.'));
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
}
```

I tried to add this on edit method

```
$logged_user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');
$logged_user_name=$this->Auth->user('username');

  if(($logged_user_id==$id)&&($logged_user_name == $username)){
      $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
```

profile.ctp

```
<div class="paginator">
    <ul>       
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit User'), ['action' => 'edit', $users->id]) ?> </li>
        <li><?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete User'), ['action' => 'delete', $users->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $users->id)]) ?> </li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?> </li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Logout'), ['action' => 'logout']) ?> </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
```

Maybe because of the get by $id causing the problems?

Comment: You are comparing the $username with the session username, but where did you find that $username & your if condition contains && which will be always false, if you will not pass both id and username to the action.

Comment: @bikash.bilz I get the username in appcontroller which i set the variable public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
 { 
   $user = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
   $this->set('username', $user['username']); 
 }

Comment: Debugg this two variable values are same or not, $logged_user_id & $id

Comment: the value of $logged_user_id = null  while $id = 41 which is correct for the current users id logging in.  what should i do now?

Comment: I wonder why is not having the same value , but I can edit my profile if currently login before i added profile method to change the url link

Comment: can you please post the return of the pr($this->Auth->user);die;

Comment: it will display nothing

Comment: Then you are not logged in. Try login to the system and then use pr

Comment: when i checked the session data using cakephp debug plugin it will display all the data, and I found out that the $id is  = 106  which have the same username of user id = 41

Comment: when i try to echo this 2 variables it shows correct data  $logged_user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');
$logged_username=$this->Auth->user('username');

Comment: If `pr` isn't generating any output for you, then you probably don't have debug enabled in your `config\app.php`.

Comment: What does the URL look like for your edit page? Does it include the username like your profile URL does? Also, you seem to imply that you have more than one user with the same username, that doesn't seem right...

Comment: the debug in app.php is always enabled on my end.  'debug' => true,     this is the url look like http://localhost/sample/users/profile/john, that username that had duplicate value is already fixed because I did not validate the username field when i first do this,

Comment: http://localhost/sample/users/profile/john   this is the current LOGIN user and the current url I want to edit,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
{
  $user = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
  $this->set('user_id', $user['id']); 
}
```

just edit your profile.ctp and change $users->id to $user_id

```
<div class="paginator">
    <ul>       
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit User'), ['action' => 'edit', $user_id]) ?> </li>
        <li><?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete User'), ['action' => 'delete', $users->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $users->id)]) ?> </li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?> </li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Logout'), ['action' => 'logout']) ?> </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
```

Explanation you always directly goes to "You are not allowed to do this." because of this in profile method

```
$user = $this->Users->find()->where(['username' => $username])->first();
```

the system is confused what profile to edit since you have duplicate username in the database for users table, so it throws and error "You are not allowed to do this." after finding the first row of data with the same "username value"

add this code to UsersTable.php  to prevent duplicate username

```
$validator
        ->requirePresence('username')
        ->notBlank('username', 'A username is required')
        ->add('username', 'unique', [
                    'rule' => 'validateUnique',
                    'provider' => 'table',
                    'message' => 'Username is already used'
             ]);
```

Comment: If you want unique usernames, then the database itself should disallow duplicates too, otherwise there is no guarantee for consistency.

Comment: @ndm thank you for the information,, I thought only the id disallow duplicates in the database and I check, we can disallow all fields if we wanted..